# Java soap webservice XML document over http apache axis

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to webservices.
I have been given a task I have to create a Java webservice using Apache tomcat 
client will call this webservice and send a request XML document

and I have to create a webservice which will red this XML and after some computation 
webservice will return response XML to the client.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

use [JAXWS](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.6/docs/).  if you want a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.